# Getting error while running a shell script from Azure Portal using C# on an Azure Linux VM

Tags: azure, shell, azure-functions

I am trying to run a shell script using `C#` but I receive an error after waiting for a lot of time to execute the command.

I am callingRunCommand() method like:-

```
vmClient.RunCommand(runCommandInput);
```

The error received is:-

> Long running operation failed with status 'Failed'. Additional
>   Info:'VM 'Linux-VM-Name' has not reported status for VM agent or
>   extensions. Verify the VM has a running VM agent and that it can
>   establish outbound connections to Azure storage. Please refer to
>   https://aka.ms/vmextensionlinuxtroubleshoot for additional VM agent
>   troubleshooting information.'

Comment: Looks like a timeout. Maybe your command is waiting for something?

Comment: It is solved. It seems the issue was with Azure VM. Tried the same on a different VM which was having same configuration and it worked.

Comment: @Chaitanya I have a similar requirement. What library or nuget pkg did you add to execute `RunCommand` on linux vm?

Comment: @John see if it helps you (apply line breaks properly)-
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute.Fluent;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute.Fluent.Models;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent.Authentication;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent.Core;